# Where do I put 覚えて in 私はコンビニですしをうります?

Tags: translation

I am going to attempt to translate an English sentence to Japanese. Where do I put the word ’覚えて’ in the sentence?

> I just remember that there is a convenient store that sells sushi

Translation: *私はコンビニですしをうります*

Comment: Contrary to the title, I think you're probably looking for 思い出す, not 覚える.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this, although I suspect my translation will be slightly wordy or unnatural. But hey, 頑張ろう。

The sentence you offered:

> 私はコンビニですしをうります

Means "I sell sushi at a convenience store."

> a convenience store that sells sushi

is expressed as:

> すしを売るコンビニ

And to put it together:

> 寿司を売るコンビニがあることを思い出しました。

If you want to literally emphasize "**just** remembered", make it 思い出したばかりです.

Comment: Oh, this might be a little clearer: 寿司を売るコンビニ**のこと**を思い出しました。Which I think emphasizes that you have personal knowledge of this konbini, not just that you know **of** it.

Comment: Dunno who downvoted you, but your translation reads as a bit awkward because it feels like you're directly translating something in a way it probably wouldn't be said in Japanese. Granted, this is probably because you were trying to use OP's phrasing, but that in and of itself felt pretty contrived. If we're thinking about a situation in which you're hanging out with friends and someone has a craving for sushi, I could see someone saying something like

>そういえば、寿司を売ってるコンビニ、この辺りにあったよな？

Using 覚える or 思い出す wouldn't be necessary unless you were trying to draw attention your remembering.